# How do you fit the ordered logit model?

Tags: regression, maximum-likelihood, ordinal-data, ordered-logit

I am reading the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_regression) on ordered logit models. As I understand it, the model is specified by:

$\Pr(y \le k | \mathbf{x}) =  \frac{1}{1 + e^{\mathbf{w} \cdot \mathbf{x} - \theta_k}}$

where $\theta_k$ are the thresholds $\theta_1 <\theta_2 < \dots < \theta_{K-1}$.
(NB: The original wiki formula has $\theta_i$ appearing on the RHS. This does not seem meaningful to me so I changed it to $k$ instead.)

This implies that the probability that the observation $\mathbf{x}$ falls in the $k$-th class is

$\Pr(y = k | \mathbf{x}) = \Pr(y \le k | \mathbf{x}) - \Pr(y \le k - 1 | \mathbf{x})$.

The article then goes on to say that to fit the model you need to find the coefficients $\mathbf{w}$ and the thresholds $\theta_k$. So far so good, except it does not tell you how to implement a procedure to find these.

My question is, how do you determine the best set of coefficients and thresholds? Is it with respect to a maximum likelihood estimator for the predicted probability for the actual class of the response?

Note that I am not interested in packages/software that can fit the ordered logit model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, typically maximum likelihood estimation is used to find the coefficients and thresholds. Of course, there's no reason why a Bayesian approach wouldn't be a reasonable way to do it either.

Comment: thanks, are you 1) able to elaborate a bit more on the Bayesian approach? 2) recommend me a reference on implementing the maximum likelihood estimator?. Also, was I correct in replacing the $i$ in the wikipedia formula with $k$?

Comment: @Alex: honestly, it's a fairly straight forward problem so it's a little hard to know where to start, other than [standard methods for glm's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_linear_model#Fitting).